Should one use a Better or Less-known CSPRNG?
I have an application that requires the choice of a CSPRNG. I see too obvious "classes" of CSPRNGs one can choose, namely an "industry standard" CSPRNG, or a CSPRNG that is still thought to be secure, but less standard. My thinking is that the less standard CSPRNG may be less of a target of cryptanalysts, given their (relative) lack of popularity, and therefore might be more secure than a standard CSPRNG.
How sound is this reasoning?

When talking about stream ciphers, I think I would trust a better analyzed cipher such as AES in CTR mode or ChaCha20. When talking about random number generators I'd trust a HashDRBG before, say, ISAAC. More analysis means less likely that somebody can come up with a new attack.

The lack of exposed weaknesses due to limited cryptanalysis should not add to your confidence in the security of a cryptographic primitive. This approach is pretty close to security through obscurity.
On a more pragmatic note, I am not a lawyer, but if your application failed due to a cryptographic primitive, you were sued, and I were called as an expert witness, I would feel that I could make a stronger case that you had made a reasonable cryptographic choice if you used a design approved by a standard recognised in your regulatory jurisdiction.
